# Trying to automate surveymonkey with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, surveymonkey

I am writing a selenium test case to automate surveymonkey.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("-incognito --no-sandbox")   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/lib64/chromium/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/WXNXWVB')
time.sleep(3) 
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_id('96247410_725897453')
vote_check.click()
time.sleep(3) 
nxt_btn = driver.find_element_by_name('Done')
nxt_btn.click() 
driver.quit()
```

And I get the flowing error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input id="96247410_725897453" name="96247410" type="radio" class="radio-button-input" value="725897453"> is not clickable at point (850, 203). Other element would receive the click: <span class="radio-button-display ">...</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `vote_check = driver.find_element_by_id('96247410_725897453')` This wont work.

Try Using :
`vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='question-field-96247410']/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/div/label/span[1]")`

Comment: For Option 1:
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='96247410_725897453']")
For Option 2:
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='96247410_725897454']")

Comment: That part works great and I understand what your doing?
Now how would I also click the Done button?

Comment: The issue is in the error message. You are trying to click some element but another element is blocking the click. Sometimes this is a popup dialog that you need to dismiss first, other times it's just the page resizing. You would have to do more investigation as to which scenario applies to your case. You may need a wait, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Find the Below Workable code:

For Option 1:

```
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='96247410_7258974‌​53']")
```

For Option 2:

```
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='96247410_7258974‌​54']")
```

For Done:

```
vote_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), ' Done')]")
```

Try at your end and let me know.